# Configuring Nginx proxy to pass through all requests except certain domains

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have a simple Nginx proxy with the following config:

```
server {
      server_name www.myserver.com;
      location / {
        proxy_pass http://mytest.pagekite.me;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
      }
    }
```

With this config all requests to `www.myserver.com` will be forwarded to `http://mytest.pagekite.me`. What I'd like to have is additional directive to pass through all other requests. Like, if the user requests `www.google.com` I'd like this proxy to forward this request.

Tried quite a few things, like:

```
server {
     server_name ~^(www\.)?(.+)$;
     location / {
       proxy_pass $request_uri;
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_buffering off;
     }
   }
```

With this config I get server error 500 when requesting pages outside of www.myserver.com.

What would be a correct config for the transparent proxying of all requests except for `www.myserver.com`?

Comment: Probably you need to define [`resolver`](http://nginx.org/r/resolver)

Comment: Tried adding `resolver 8.8.8.8;` line to the `location` context, getting same 500 error :/

Comment: Look into error.log. There should be reason

Comment: Aha, here is the error: `invalid URL prefix in "/generate_204", client: 92.60.254.37, server: ~^(www\.)?(.+)$, request: "GET http://173.194.34.100/generate_204 HTTP/1.1", host: "clients3.google.com"`

Comment: this request is made by an android device to catch if this is a captive portal